# How to avoid calling Base class properties while creating derived class objects?

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties

I have a base class ProductDetails which is responsible for parsing the productstring, there is another class SelfManufactured which inherits from the baseclass ProductDetails, there is another class - ThirdPartyProduct , which inherits from the SelfManufactured class and has additional details which are specific to this class, like ThirdPartyName, ThirdPartyAddress.

a) For SelfManufactured product the string should be - prefixed with 0

b) For ThirdPartyProduct product the string should be - prefixed with 1

workflow goes like this:

I create a  ThirdPartyProduct object using following code:

```
private void ThirdParty_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {            
            ThirdPartyProduct  thirdparty = new ThirdPartyProduct ("1000", "200", "PROD1",
                "XYZW", "ABCD");
            string thirdpartyProductString = thirdparty.ToString();                

   }
```

if you check the variable thirdpartyProductString in below code it is : appending 0 and then 1.
It appends 0 and then 1 instead what I would like to have is only "1" getting prefixed. 
 I guess since SelfManufactured class is also called while creating ThirdParty object, it keeps appending values, I would like to have a way that ToString() does not append values when not needed.

```
ProductDetails.cs
using System;
namespace product
{
    public class ProductDetails
    {
    private readonly string _productString;

    public string ProductString
    {
        get => ToString();
    }      


        public ProductDetails(string productId, string productName, string productLot)
        {           

            _productString =  // somevalue here....
        }
        public override string MyString()
        {
            return _productString;
        }                  
    }
}


SelfManufactured.cs

public class SelfManufactured : ProductDetails
    {         

        public override string MyString()
        {
            string str = string.Empty;
            str = "additional value of 0" +  // append the identifier as '0' with product string
            return str;
        }
    }    



ThirdPartyProduct.cs  

public class ThirdPartyProduct : SelfManufactured
    {          
        public string ThirdPartyName { get; set; }
        public string ThirdPartyAddress { get; set; }                   

        public override string MyString()
        {
            string str = string.Empty;
            // append the identifier as '1' with product string and add additional details with the string.

            return str;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the leading characters being added? Why are you putting an integer in front of a string which will drop leading zeroes : str = (int)ProductType.ThirdParty.  Why do you need base.ToString()?    Looks like you are taking a class and converting to a string.  Shouldn't you be referencing a string object in the base?

Comment: I wonder if a lot of the detail in this question isn't related to the problem. The actual question seems to be about the behavior and inheritance of `ToString`. Are the parts about XML and the constructors relevant? If not, removing them would make the question much easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling base.ToString() in "ThirdPartyProduct" class, it obviously calls the base class ToString() method and it adds "0" to it and making the final string as "101000200PROD1XYZWABCD"

If you don't want to do that then you can refer "ProductString" property of ProductDetails class directly from ToString() method of ThirdPartyProduct class. See below my changes

**ProductDetails.cs** - I am returning the private read-only from here.

```
public string ProductString
{
    get { return _productString; }
}
```

Then the ToString() method of ThirdPartyProduct.cs class made to following changes

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string str = string.Empty;
        // append the identifier as '0' with product string and add additional details with the string.
        str = (int)ProductType.ThirdParty + ProductString + ThirdPartyName + ThirdPartyAddress;
        return str;
    }
```

Made changes at the following line -

str = (int)ProductType.ThirdParty + **base.ToString()** + ThirdPartyName + ThirdPartyAddress;

to

str = (int)ProductType.ThirdParty + **ProductString** + ThirdPartyName + ThirdPartyAddress;

Note:- I hope always the ThirdPartyProduct class should not append "0", then above solution should be fine, else you need to think of other approach for the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a property in class ProductDetails called "TypeOfProduct". So in SelfManufactured.ToString(), instead of hard-coding the product type, use the property's value:

```
str = (int)TypeOfProduct + base.ToString();
```

Then, in ThirdPartyProduct, there's no need to use the product type as this is taken care of in the base class. So instead call base.ToString() followed by the class-specific details:

```
str = base.ToString() + ThirdPartyName + ThirdPartyAddress;
```